# Why does 'document.querySelectorAll' only target immediate children?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

According to the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for `document.querySelectorAll`, the syntax is

```
elementList = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
```

where

```
*selectors* is a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas
```

But this doesn't seem to work for wildcard child selectors. Consider the following HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <p>One <a href="#">Link One</a> </p>
  <p>Two <a href="#">Link Two</a> </p>
  <p>Three <a href="#">Link Three</a> </p>

  <a href=#>Outer Link One</a>
  <a href=#>Outer Link Two</a>
  <a href=#>Outer Link Three</a>
</div>
```

with the following JS

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#container *:not(a)'), 
function(node) {
  node.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
});
```

and the following CSS

```
#container {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container *:not(a) {
  color: green;
}
```

You will see that the css `*:not(a)` excludes all anchor tags from the style whereas the same selector used in JS only seems to exclude the anchor tags that are immediate children of `#container`, as if it were `#container > a`

Why does this happen? And is there a way to get the same result as the CSS in the `querySelectorAll` method?

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kh0uqjqc/1/)

Comment: Seems to works exactly as expected, the `p` elements are bold, and the styles are inherited by the anchors ?

Comment: You're being thrown off by the fact that <a> tags have default color which overrides the custom <p> color. https://jsfiddle.net/kh0uqjqc/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kh0uqjqc/3/ <- doesn't really change the set styles of the anchors, just the parent element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does 'document.querySelectorAll' only target immediate children?

It doesn't, it looks for all descendants.

You're making the `p` elements that contain the `a` elements bold, and the `a` elements are inheriting that; whereas `a` elements have their own color. If you reverse the bold and color so the bold is applied by CSS and the color by JavaScript, you'll see that `querySelectorAll` is doing the same thing the CSS is doing:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#container *:not(a)'), 
function(node) {
  node.style.color = "green";
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container *:not(a) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>One <a href="#">Link One</a> </p>
  <p>Two <a href="#">Link Two</a> </p>
  <p>Three <a href="#">Link Three</a> </p>

  <a href=#>Outer Link One</a>
  <a href=#>Outer Link Two</a>
  <a href=#>Outer Link Three</a>
</div>
```

> And is there a way to get the same result as the CSS in the `querySelectorAll` method?

The CSS and `querySelectorAll` are already addressing the same elements. :-) If you want the `a` elements not to be bold, you'll have to tell them not to inherit that from their ancestors:

```
#container a {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Example:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#container *:not(a)'), 
function(node) {
  node.style.fontWeight = "bold";
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#container *:not(a) {
  color: green;
}
#container a {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>One <a href="#">Link One</a> </p>
  <p>Two <a href="#">Link Two</a> </p>
  <p>Three <a href="#">Link Three</a> </p>

  <a href=#>Outer Link One</a>
  <a href=#>Outer Link Two</a>
  <a href=#>Outer Link Three</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Silly me.